# To what key does Dvorak Humoresque #7 modulate at the Piu Lento?

Tags: key, analysis, modulation

The melodic part of Humoresque number 7, beginning at m. 25, changes to another key.  What key is it.  The main body is G flat major.

Answer (score 0):

It is primarily in A major, but it also has portions that sound more like F# minor — the relative minor of A major. This allows Dvorak to easily modulate back to Gb major in the final section of the piece, since F# minor and Gb major are enharmonically equivalent parallel modes.

Comment: Doesn't this come under fire as a 'close for this community-specific reason' question? Answering it will only encourage others!

Comment: @Tim It's a well-defined section of a work. My feeling is that it qualifies for on-topic status.